# Parse Server - Login with Apple from Backend

Tags: node.js, authentication, parse-platform

I am unable to find the function for logging in with Apple using Nodejs. Facebook has a nice way of logging in like this:

```
let facebookAuth = { 
    id: facebookUserId, 
    access_token: facebookToken, 
}

Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(facebookAuth, { success: function(user){}, error: function(error){})
```

But I'm not sure about apple. I have my authData:

```
let appleAuth = {
        id: userId,
        token: token
    }
```

If there's a way, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

So here's my progress, I think I found the function.

```
let authData = {
        authData : {
            apple: {
                id: userId,
                token: token
            }
        }
    }

Parse.User.logInWith('apple', authData).then(function (user) {
    console.log(user)
}, function(err){
    console.log(err)
});
```

But I'm getting an error 252: This authentication method is unsupported.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with this:

```
let authData = {
  authData: {
    id: id,
    token: token
  }
}

Parse.User.logInWith('apple', authData).then(user => {
  console.log(user);
  window.location.reload();
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```